# UILabel text not showing up in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

For some reason I'm fetching information from my core data model, but all that it's displaying is a "(" in my `UITableView`. Now I've done the following:

```
NSLog (@"%@",reading.a1);
```

and it logs the following:

```
   2013-10-22 02:30:27.911  [6366:60b] (
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
)
2013-10-22 02:30:27.914  [6366:60b] (
    "Proin condimentum et felis vel posuere."
)
2013-10-22 02:30:27.917  [6366:60b] (
    "Proin sit amet est eget felis sagittis tempus."
)
```

which is just some latin dummy text that was placed up in the server. So I see that information is being pulled properly, but it's just not coming up in `UITableViewCell` for some reason. I have the following code from my custom cell:

```
#import "CustomCell"

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // configure control(s)
        self.snippet = [[UILabel alloc ]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 0, 200, 80)];
        self.snippet.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.snippet.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.snippet.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

        self.healthReading = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 300, 30)];
        self.healthReading.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.healthReading.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12.0f];

        //[self addSubview:self.healthReading];
        [self addSubview:self.snippet];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and in my `UITableviewController` I have the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    FinalRead *readings = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%@",readings.a1);
    cell.snippet.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", readings.a1];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIImageView *imv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 23, 60, 60)];
    imv.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"AppIcon60x60.png"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imv];


    return cell;

}
```

so for some weird reason it's just coming up with "(" in the cell. Any ideas?

Comment: what kind of property is your `a1` for your class `FinalRead`. With a `NSLog` it might not appear some "(" and ")" if it is a `NSString`.

Comment: plz show the out put screen u r getting @john

Comment: It is an NSString. Basically it's declared in an NSManagedObject and I'm setting my label text equal to the returned value from NSFetchController.

Comment: Yeah, the latin dummy text is what is being printed out in the console.

Comment: It looks like an array. Please check

Comment: put a breakpoint after `cell.snippet.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", readings.a1];` and then type in your debugger : `po cell.snippet`

Comment: I ended up with the following: <UILabel: 0x16da4930; frame = (90 0; 200 80); text = '(
    "Lorem ipsum dolor ...'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x16da49d0>>

Comment: You might have a problem with retrieving the value `readings.a1`. You are storing more than the string value because you have "(" and ")".
Can you also try replacing `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", readings.a1]` by `[NSString stringWithString: readings.a1]` ?

Comment: According to the debug readings.a1 has a property called text , why don´t you try: `cell.snippet.text = readings.a1.text;`

Comment: Okay, I feel stupid. Apparently I was pulling an array and storing that array in my core data model and it didn't know the difference, but neither did I so yeah... All is well. Thanks everyone!!